# Nestjs Global Validation Pipe unable to Parse Boolean Query Param

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

In following controller, in the GET call I intend to pass a boolean parameter.

```
@Controller('tests')
export class TestController {
    constructor(private readonly testService: TestService) {}

    @Get()
    async getTests(@Query() params: QueryParamDto) {
        return await this.testService.getTests(params.var);
    }
}
```

and the Service method understands the type of `params.var` as a `boolean`.

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    @Get()
    async getTests(var: boolean) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

The `QueryParamDto` looks like.

```
export class QueryParamDto {
    @IsDefined()
    @IsBoolean()
    var: boolean;
}
```

I have defined a Global Validation Pipe in `main.ts`.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
    }),
  );
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

However, when I make a call to the endpoint `/tests?var=true` it is unable to parse the var as a boolean and errors.

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "var must be a boolean value"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

My understanding is that `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true...})` should automatically parse the params type as defined in the Dto, in this case `var` as `boolean` in `QueryParamDto`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform` means that the result of `plainToClass` from `class-transformer` will be the resulting parameter passed to your route handler. Normally this would be fine, but query and url parameters always come in as `string`s, so you either need to add your own `@Transform()` to make them get transformed properly, or use the [`transformOptions.enableImplicitConversion`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/interfaces/external/class-transform-options.interface.ts#L47) option

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this issue, my solution is as below:

```
@IsDefined()
@Transform(({ value }) => {
     if (value === 'true') return true;
     if (value === 'false') return false;
          return value;
      })
@IsBoolean()
var: boolean;
```